# Show the number of all tables, views and base tables

Tags: postgresql, system-tables

How to do that?
I was thinking of something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.table_name), COUNT(B.table_name)
FROM information_schema.tables AS A, information_schema.views AS B;
```

But sadly it gives me bad numbers (it multiplies the first COUNT with the second one) and I still don't know how to get BASE TABLES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`information_schema.tables` includes tables **and** views, so you only need:

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.tables
where table_type in ('VIEW', 'BASE TABLE')
```

If you want the numbers separately for each type, use a `group by`

```
select table_type, count(*)
from information_schema.tables
where table_type in ('VIEW', 'BASE TABLE')
group by table_type
```

---

The reason your statement isn't working is because you are creating a cross join (cartesian product) between the two system view.

Comment: Thanks but still, I guess I forgot to mention that I need to get the numbers separately. (Number of all tables, number of views and number of base table)

Comment: Awesome! One more thing, how to show the number of ALL tables also in the same query? (views + base tables) Like: all tables, views, base table

Comment: @Tripper: simply remove the `where` clause. But regular tables **are** base tables in that view. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html

Comment: Yea, I get it, but I want that in the same query, because for now it shows me views and base tables only. But I want to add in this query also the number of ALL tables w/o deleting the `where` (smt. like
    `where table_type in ('ALL', 'VIEW', 'BASE TABLE')`
althought I know there isn't such thing as ALL in table_type
Maybe something like `count(table_type = 'VIEW') + count(table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: @Tripper You **will** get "all" if you completely remove the `where` clause